# Perl regex becoming greedy when used (.*?) with anchors

Tags: regex, perl, greedy

I have a perl regex to add youtube video link to video tag. The YouTube videos link can be within anchors sometimes and sometimes without anchors. I have checked anchor with any value using (.*?) but it behaving as greedy.  below is the regex that I am using.

```
$text =~ s#(^|\s|\>)(?:<a(.*?)\>)?((http|https)://(?:www.)?(?:youtu.be/|youtube.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=|/watch\?[a-z_=]+&(amp;)?v=))([\w-]{11}))[\?&\w;\=\+\-\.]*(\<\/a\>)?#$1\[video\]$3\[\/video\]#isg;
```

Please help to make it non-greedy.

Sample of input data:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=639296402756602" target="_blank">https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=639296402756602</a>

<a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gTw2EDkaDQ" target="_blank">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gTw2EDkaDQ</a>
```

I am expecting below ouput:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=639296402756602" target="_blank">https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=639296402756602</a>

[video]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gTw2EDkaDQ[/video]
```

but it returns only youtube link. it is ignoring facebook video link.

```
[video]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gTw2EDkaDQ[/video]
```

Comment: can you add samples of the input data?

Comment: added sample input data. please look into.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion the `.*?` is greedy? Can you specify what output you expect? The first line of sample input does not contain a link to youtube, but to a facebook picture.

Comment: I have edited expected result and current result it is giving in question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you *really* want to match `>` characters?  I bet you don't... So *don't use `.*`* and that will solve your greediness problem.  Use `[^>]*` instead.  It's guaranteed to stop as soon as it hits the first `>` (even without tacking on a `?`) because `>` doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

`$text =~ s#(^|\s|\>)(?:<a(.*?)\>)?((http|https)://(?:www.)?(?:youtu.be/|youtube.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=|/watch\?[a-z_=]+&(amp;)?v=))([\w-]{11}))[\?&\w;\=\+\-\.]*(\<\/a\>)?#$1\[video\]$3\[\/video\]#isg;`

This regexp is unreadable and no one will want to read it. Remember, that regular expressions are programms too, and they need code formatting too.

Always use `smx` modifiers with all regexps, this is very good practice, like `always use strict and warnings`.

**m** - Treat string as multiple lines. That is, change "^" and "$" from matching the start or end of line only at the left and right ends of the string to matching them anywhere within the string.

**s** - Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.
Used together, as /ms, they let the "." match any character whatsoever, while still allowing "^" and "$" to match, respectively, just after and just before newlines within the string.

**x** - Extend your pattern's legibility by permitting whitespace and comments.

Then your code will look much more readable and you will see that it contains many unusable capturing groups, and dead code, and small bugs, like using of unescaped `.` in url capturing group.

After all modifications and as Dave Sherohman says using `[^>]*` instead of `.*?` your code will look much better, isn't it?. Check this out:

```
$text =~ s{
                (?:<a[^>]*>)?
                (
                    http[s]?://
                    (?:www[.])?
                    youtu[.]?be(?:[.]com)?
                    (?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=|/watch\?[a-z_=]+&(?:amp;)?v=)
                )
                ([\w-]{11})
                [^<]*
                (?:</a>)?
            }
            {
                \[video\]$1$2\[/video\]
            }smxgi;
```

And it works fine!

Comment: personally I don't agree with the suggestion in Perl Best Practices of adding 'xms' to all regexes - I'd rather they only appeared when they were actually being used. Regexes on multi-line variables have tended to be less common in my experience than single-line variables, and so I'd rather regexes dealing with these stood out with an explicit 'm' or 's' (or both) if needed, rather than being blindly applied everywhere.

Comment: Is there problem to use all 3 modifiers by default and write one-line regexps? If its hard to write them, there is module Regexp::DefaultFlags on cpan, that will do this for you.

Comment: plusplus, re flag detractors like you are missing the point of the policy - when `m` and `s` are applied, there is absolutely no doubt what `.` or `^`/`$` mean. Enabling them leads to code that's straightforward readable with a consistent meaning of the metacharacters. So do apply them blindly, even globally: `use re '/msx';` - but only for new code, of course, not existing REs. (Regexp::DefaultFlags is [not needed anymore since 5.14](http://p3rl.org/perl5140delta#use-re-flags).)

Comment: The regex provided by the OP may be unreadable, but your regex isn't any better, really: a) This `[.]` does not do what you think. b) Crappy indentation. c) Non-greedy `[^>]*?` is sub-optimal here. d) You don't have to escape `[` and `]` in the replacement text. e) The /x modifier does not cut whitespace off from the replacement text. And I fear the longer you look at it, the more issues you will encounter...

Comment: Your issues looks disputable: a) What [.] does here? I think it matches point character b) Whats wrong with my indentation? You can edit my post if you dont like it. It's much more readable that original. never saw anywhere rules of indentation of regexps c) i'm not so good to think about optimization of regexps, sorry. fix it if you can. d) in original regexp [] was escaped, i leave them as is, my goal was to show right way. e) don't think that this whitespace matters here.

Comment: Erm, actually, I said to use `[^>]*`, not `[^>]*?`, even pointing out that the `?` was unnecessary when using a negated character class instead of `.*`.